# Slow ethernet, despite GbE hardware: Searching for causes

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I am having issues with slow network speeds in my home network between 2 boxes.
Here are the specs:

Box1:
[ASRock H97 Performance](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Fatal1ty%20H97%20Performance/#Specification),
Manjaro

Box2:
[ASRock FM2A78M-ITX+](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/FM2A78M-ITX+/#Specification),
Debian 9

Switch:
[Netgear GS305v2](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS305v2.aspx)

Both boxes are connected to the switch with Cat.7 (10m and 2m) cables.
So everything should work with Gigabit Ethernet, right?

Yet running iperf gives this result:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   105 MBytes  88.5 Mbits/sec   32             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   103 MBytes  86.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Where do I start looking for the problem?

Edit:
On one side I ran `iperf3 -s` on the other `iperf3 -c xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.
I also testet file transfers via NFS and rsync over ssh, resulting in the same speed.

The output of `ethtool` on the debian machine:

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                               link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
        Link detected: yes
```

And on the Manjaro machine:

```
Settings for enp0s25:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        MDI-X: off (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Looks like the Manjaro interface is setup for 100Mb/s only.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your `iperf` command line.

Comment: Please check the output of `ethtool eth0` on both computers.

Answer (score 3):

Enabling auto-negotiation for the network interface with `ethtool -s enp0s25 autoneg on` fixed it.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!